# How to remove quotation at the of the raw content in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, trim

I have tried to remove the leading and trailing qutation marks from the contents of my MySQL table wit the following query:

```
UPDATE `example_table` 
   SET `title` = TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM `title`)
```

But It just remove my starting quotations and I still have the ending quotations like below:

```
NAme      Language 
Sam          EN"
MAri         ES-TR"
```

Anyone knows how can I remove them as well?

Comment: Some alternate solutions which may work for you under given conditions. If your original data contains leading and trailing double quotes for all of them, you may just fetch a `substring`, or `replace` if rest of the string does not contain a double quote.

Comment: Your query works just fine. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6a50/1. Are you sure you're updating the correct column?

Comment: @peterm yes I am sure

Comment: @theghostofc would you please write me the query with substring or replace? I also think that my original data may have quotes since I have imported it from an excel file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that you have trailing spaces

Try

```sql
UPDATE `example_table` 
   SET `Language` = TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM TRIM(`Language`));
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a1cc/1)** demo

**UPDATE** A version with `REPLACE()`

```sql
UPDATE `example_table` 
   SET `Language` = TRIM(REPLACE(`Language`, '"', ''));
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c349/1)** demo

Note: *this version will replace all double quotes not only leading and trailing*

Comment: This also does not work. Can you write me an example of command with replace or substring

Comment: @user2058811 It's fairly simple, but anyway see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following SQL query:

```
UPDATE `example_table` 
    SET `Language` = SUBSTRING(`Language`, 2, LENGTH(`Language`) - 2);
```

This assumes that all the data that you have is in the format `"xxxx"` or `"AB-CD"`, i.e. only leading and trailing double quotes and no extra white spaces or tabs.

If your data has leading and trailing white spaces then you may try the following SQL query:

```
UPDATE `example_table` 
    SET `Language` = SUBSTRING(TRIM(`Language`), 2, LENGTH(TRIM(`Language`)) - 2);
```

These queries will work fine even if your data contains quotes e.g. `"EQ-"EW"`

> Please take this as a starting point and not as a copy-paste solution.